# Realtek wifi driver for RTL8723DE for linux kernel version 5.11.0-26-generic (ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, realtek

Is there a version of the RTL8723E driver, like here: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88 for linux kernel version 5.11.0.26? This github, which I've used before has not been updated since September 2020, and it does not work (dropped packets and long travel times from ping) with the current version of the kernel.

The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` is as follows:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [10ec:d723]
        DeviceName: WLAN
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [103c:8319]
        Kernel driver in use: rtl8723de
```

I've temporarily had to roll back to 5.8.0-63, for which I know the version on that webpage works when compiled, but I've not found one that works with 5.11.0.

Do I need to wait for that page to update, or is there another version somewhere that I could try?

Comment: I note that there still isn't an update on this package, and the kernel version has risen to 5.15.0.43